# Where can I find TTY and curses documentation for Unix?

Tags: scripting, tcl, expect, curses, tty

I'm working on automation tools for an ERP program running on SCO Unix.
See my questions on Expect:

- [(Tcl/Expect) clear screen after exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987302/tcl-expect-clear-screen-after-exit)
- [Expect - get variable from screen region based on row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988811/expect-get-variable-from-screen-region-based-on-row-and-column)

Where can I find (either locally or on the web) resources for understanding what control characters are used in a session, and more specifically, determining a field location on the screen during an interaction with the ERP program?

Comment: did you try *man curses* (at the prompt of that unix box)?

Comment: man: curses not found
'apropos curses' gives me: VtControl (VTCL) - bring server into and out of curses raw/cooked mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific control characters for a given terminal type are stored in the `terminfo` database. curses reads the value of `$TERM` when initializing and uses it to find and extract the relevant sequences for the various terminal operations.

Comment: Very helpful.  'man terminfo' gave me more detail than I was ready for :p

Comment: Did you find any better way of accessing it from Tcl than `exec tput`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really clear what you are asking, but one source of documentation on curses is the GNU implementation at http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses. As far as 'control characters' go, well that depends on what terminal you use - yours probably understands ANSI codes - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the X/Open Group released a new version of their standard in November 2009 (previous version was released in 1996), and it is available free on the web from their bookstore as Technical Standard - [X/Open Curses, Issue 7](http://www.opengroup.org/pubs/catalog/c094.htm).  You have to register, but access is free (and registration does not lead to an inundation of email, etc).

The previous version, Issue 4, Version 2 (from July 1996), is no longer available from X/Open.  Given the newness of Issue 7, the new features are unlikely to be widely implemented yet, but look for changes in the next few years.

Comment: The only *new* feature in issue 7 was [`tiparm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Formatting-Output), which was in ncurses a [week](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#index-t20100109) after this answer.